# Stripe subscriptions.create - can you force use of payment intent?

Tags: stripe-payments

**Background:**

Having obtained a `paymentMethodId` from the client with Stripe Elements, I am doing this on the server side:

1. `stripe.paymentMethods.attach(..)`,
2. `stripe.customers.update(...default_payment_method: ...)`.
3. `stripe.subscriptions.create(..)`.

When additional action is required by 3DSecure, the `subscription` object (returned from `create` or fetched at a later date) includes a `pending_setup_intent`, which gives the info needed to resolve the intent (and i've got that working ok).

However if we run the `subscriptions.create` call when there aren't any payment methods on the Stripe Customer, the `subscription` object doesn't include a `pending_setup_intent` or anything else to indicate that the subscription doesn't have a way to pay.

**Question:**

Short of waiting for webhooks is there some way to have reasonably high confidence that the first payment on the subscription is likely to succeed, ie. there is a card, it's going to accept the payment (and yes, the 3DSecure stuff is sorted)?

**Notes:**

Although I'm not using trials on the subscription, the `billing_cycle_anchor` is in the future to provide a free period (basically a trial, but not explicitly making use of the stripe trial concept).

I'm using Stripe API version: 2015-03-24 (upgrading is a lower priority than resolving this)

**Further clarification:**

At the point we make the call to `stripe.subscriptions.create()`, the code is not aware of whether the paymentMethod was successfully attached and set as the default (I suppose we could check this, but my hope was that Stripe can handle that for us). For example when using the test card `4000000000000002` the payment method is not attached.

The call to stripe.subscriptions.create is of the form:

```
{
  customer: stripeCustomerId,
  billing_cycle_anchor: 1606946400,
  cancel_at_period_end: undefined,
  items: [{plan: "pro_annual"}],
  prorate: false,
  expand: ["pending_setup_intent", "pending_setup_intent.latest_attempt"]
}
```

Comment: "the subscription object doesn't include a pending_setup_intent or anything else" -> Can you explain more, what does your Subscription object look like? Are you just creating a PaymentMethod, attaching to a Customer and then creating a Subscription on that Customer? Do you have a request ID for that Subscription.create() request?

Comment: hi @hmunoz - i have added a "further clarification" section to the question. an example request is - `req_re8c4FqXCoLmUiz`

Comment: ok so there is no `pending_setup_intent` as there is no `Invoice` on the Subscription, the first payment is weeks out. The first payment will be attempted asynchronously so once an Invoice is created and finalized, there should be a `latest_invoice.payment_intent` on the Subscription.

Comment: but if i use the test card `4000002760003184` and do everything else the same i do get a  `pending_setup_intent` see `req_B0RDMQ5rnLHn35`.

Comment: That card is for requesting authentication and you probably have (default) Radar Rules that caught this and requested authentication up front, which is why a `pending_setup_intent` is created for this as it determined that the initial payment would require authentication due to the nature of the 3184 test card token.